# Magento 1.9 cache permissions being set as 777

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, security, permissions

I am getting an issue with Magento where my cache files are being set to 777 every time I re-cache the site.

Is this standard behavior as it seems to be wrong to me, as far as I know no file should ever be set to 777 as it's a security hole.

If this is not the case does anyone know how I can stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

The default permissions for cache files are `600`

This is defined in [`Mage_Cache_Backend_File`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/lib/Mage/Cache/Backend/File.php):

```
class Mage_Cache_Backend_File extends Zend_Cache_Backend_File
{
    /**
     * Default options for the File cache adapter
     *
     *  @var array
     */
    protected $_options = array(
        'cache_dir'              => null,    // Path to cache files
        'file_locking'           => true,    // Best to keep enabled
        'read_control'           => false,   // Use a checksum to detect corrupt data
        'read_control_type'      => 'crc32', // If read_control is enabled, which checksum algorithm to use
        'hashed_directory_level' => 2,       // How many characters should be used to create sub-directories
        'hashed_directory_perm'  => 0770,    // Filesystem permissions for created directories
        'file_name_prefix'       => 'mage',  // Prefix for cache directories created
        'cache_file_perm'        => 0660,    // Filesystem permissions for created files
    );
```

But these default settings can be overridden. Please check your `app/etc/local.xml` if it contains an entry similar to

```
<cache>
    <backend_options>
        <cache_file_perm>777</cache_file_perm>
    </backend_options>
</cache>
```

Comment: In Magento 1.9 `'cache_file_perm'        => 0660` no longer exist. I had my cache file set to 600 which is causing permission issues, not sure where to change it. Update the local.xml doesn't seem to do anything.